# Why does Play action fail with "no suitable driver found" with Slick and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I'm writing a Scala web app using [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) 2.1.1 using a local Postgres database along with [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) 1.0.0, and I'm running into what seems to be a contradiction here.

This is the error I'm running into:

```
[SQLException: No suitable driver found for postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres]
56  
57  def instance = Action {
58    Database.forURL("postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver") withSession {
59      val q = Retailer.map(_.name)
60      Ok(views.html.instance(q.list, newRForm))
61    }
62  }
63
```

Where `user` and `password` are respectively the `username` and `password` of the Postgres database.

In [java error (No suitable driver found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130254/java-error-no-suitable-driver-found) I found:

1. You'll need to load the driver somewhere using `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");`
2. You'll need the PostgreSQL driver's jar file in the classpath of your program.

In `Application.scala` I have the following block of code:

```
{
  println(ConfigFactory.load().getString("db.default.url"))
  println(Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"))
}
```

Rerunning `play compile` results in:

```
(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres
class org.postgresql.Driver
[error] application -

! @6ei1nhkop - Internal server error, for (GET) [/instance] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:326) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:324) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
        at scala.slick.session.Database$$anon$2.createConnection(Database.scala:105) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(Session.scala:207) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn(Session.scala:207) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.close(Session.scala:221) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
```

Then I run `play dependencies` and the postgres .jar is resolved!

```
Here are the resolved dependencies of your application:
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| ←[32mpostgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4←[0m         | ←[37mats:ats_2.10:1.0-SNAPSHOT←[0m                     | ←[37mAs postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar←[0m |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Why can't a suitable driver be found?

**conf/application.conf**

```
# Database configuration
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
db.default.user=user    
db.default.password=password
```

**project/Build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName    = "ats"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here, 
    jdbc,
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"      % "1.0.0",
    "postgresql"         %  "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here    
  )
```

I also have `postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar` and `slick_2.10-1.0.1-RC1.jar` in my `/lib` file, and my local Postgres version from doing a `SELECT version();` is **9.2.4** The postgres driver resolution seems to be resolving to the 9.1 .jar though, and when I comment out the app dependency to let `/lib` be included on its own, `/lib` doesn't seem to be on Play's CLASSPATH.

I know that the Postgres url is correct, and I'm able to connect to my database when my application first launches.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are mixing things up.

> So then I looked at this question which says...
>
> 1. You'll need to load the driver somewhere. Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
> 2. You'll need the postgresql driver .jar file in the classpath of your program.

This is not applicable in this case. You have a framework that takes care of these things for you. That question you refer to is describing how to access a database with "raw" jdbc.

---

Here's how you should do it.

First of all you can simplify the configuration part. `5432` is the default port for postresql and `localhost` is also the default host. Username and password should be placed outside of the url.

```
# Database configuration
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=jdbc:postgres:postgres
db.default.user=user    
db.default.password=password
```

Now define proper sbt dependencies. Just remove the jar files from the `/lib` folder and update your dependencies to get the latest PostgreSQL driver (9.2) by changing your `Build.scala` appDependencies. Be aware that the groupId has changed from `postgresql` to `org.postgresql`.

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here, 
  jdbc,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.0",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41"
)
```

And finally you should change your controller to resolve the datasource from configuration:

```
def instance = Action {
  Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource()) withSession {
    val q = Retailer.map(_.name)
    Ok(views.html.instance(q.list, newRForm))
  }
}
```

Comment: Hum. forURL vs forDataSource is like driver vs datasource in jdbc [http://fernandezpablo85.github.io/2013/04/07/slick_connection_pooling.html]